# new bonfire install not working. Error message about .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, bonfire

Just trying to set up a new bonfire install. I've finished the install process and when I launch the site, I get the welcome page no problem. 
But when i click on the sign in button, i get the following error message:

> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

The URL looks like:

```
 http://myserver/testsite/login
```

At one point during the install, i got the following messages:

> Please set the .htaccess RewriteBase setting to: RewriteBase
>   /testsite/ Please remove the install folder and return to Bonfire

I've done a "find / -name .htaccess" on my box and it found a few:

```
/var/www/testsite/.htaccess
/var/www/testsite/install.old/.htaccess
/var/www/testsite/bonfire/application/.htaccess
/var/www/testsite/bonfire/application/cache/.htaccess
/var/www/testsite/bonfire/codeigniter/.htaccess
```

I've tried changing the one in /var/www/testsite cuz it seemed to be the main one. 
But I'm still getting the same error message.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following line to the file

> /var/www/bonfire/application/config/config.php

code:

```
 $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mod_rewrite` is enabled, don't forget to turn it on in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /testsite/
</IfModule>
```

If you think it might not be on, run this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 restart
```